# What is the name for a rectangle that is not a square?

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition

A square is a special case of a rectangle. What is a single-word term for a rectangle that is not a square?  I am looking for a word that *excludes* squares.  I am also looking for a word that is *not* "rectangle".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called oblong. The following picture is from wikipedia.

[image]

Comment: An oblong includes ellipses.

Comment: @empty: only in botany. Not in mathematics.

Comment: @TonyK I don't know that *oblong* is a universally accepted math term. At large, *non-square rectangle* looks to be its very last [listed meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblong):

***Adjective***

*1. Longer than wide.*

*2. Roughly rectangular or ellipsoidal.*

***Noun***

*1. Something with an oblong shape.*

*2. A rectangle having length greater than width.*

Comment: @dxiv: The first professional dictionary I consulted ([Chambers 21st Century Dictionary](http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=oblong&title=21st)) has non-square rectangle as the _only_ definition.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is : "A rectangular with two distinct sidelengths"

If you talk about one specific rectangular, you can just call it a rectangular. This usually implies that you do not mean a square because you did not name it a square.

But if you are talking about rectangulars in general, usually squares are included.

I do not know whether there is a common name.

Comment: You could also refer to a square as rectangular, so that does seem to solve the issue here.